# Create a grouped array from another list of array items

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of apps with ids and categories like this:

```
[apps] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 0
                        [categoryid] => 0
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 31265
                        [categoryid] => 12
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 15965
                        [categoryid] => 2
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 16554
                        [categoryid] => 12
                    )
)
```

I am trying to get all apps for a category based on this request. So, the resultant output for:

```
For CategoryId 12:
----------------
[apps] => Array
            (
                [0] => 31265
                [1] => 16554
            )

For CategoryId 2:
----------------
[apps] => Array
            (
                [0] => 15965
            )

For CategoryId 0:
----------------
[apps] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )
```

I believe i need to use nested foreach loops, but is there an efficient method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cycle through them, and place them into category-arrays:

```
foreach ( $apps as $app ) {
  $catArray[ $app[CategoryID] ][] = $app;
}
```

This should result in an array whose key represents a category, and whose nested arrays represent those apps in that category.

I've worked up a demo of this online at: http://codepad.org/WZXIvQ58

Comment: Yup.. had just started writing this.